# Position mask while rendering

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

How can I position a mask loading layer and its message in the vertical and horizontal center while the view is still rendering? I want my controller to handle it. Is there another solution than masking after rendering?

What I tried:

`oView.getEl().mask( "Loading..." );` this will be displayed before rendering is done. The message box is displayed at the top of the panel. `setloading`'s message is what I want. However:

- `setLoading()` is not locked to the panel/view. If you drag the window/panel, the loading mask with message stays in the drag start and does not move with its window/panel. The loading message works perfectly `setLoading( 'Waiting...' );`
- `mask()` locks to the panel/view (yea!). But it gets displayed at the panel's top not center.

Comment: Please provide is with code examples of what you tried already?

Comment: See my edit for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution. I do mask the correct part. But there was no height set for the view panel. So currently I must set a fix height for each panel, then the mask message is centered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Ext.getBody().mask("Loading");
```

Comment: I want the specific view to be masked, not the window and not the body.

Comment: What you are doing is not necessarily wrong, but the timing of your mask may occur when the container size you are masking is not yet calculated. In all cases mask is applied to an Element object not the component. So just make sure you are masking the correct element.

Comment: I came up with a solution. I do mask the correct part. But there was no height set for the view panel. So currently I must set a fix height for each panel, then the mask message is centered...